# JQuery not working with Handlebars

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, handlebars.js

I have included the js file in the handebars (hbs) file, testing with alert I see the files are included. but none of the JQuery functions work, which I really need.

here is how I include jquery and the js files:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="js/data.js"></script>
  <script src="js/helpers.js"></script>
```

and here is how I get the files in public folder in my app js:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

The problem is, alert works, but other functions that uses JQuery don't. Any ideas why not? Thanks.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. What does this have to do with handlebars? Or what "including a js file in the handlebars file" means. Could you provide more code so we can tell what jQuery functions you're even trying to use? And any error messages that may come up? Thanks

Comment: Hi. Thanks, I solved it. I had double reference to the files in my code that messed it up.

Comment: Cool, glad to hear it. If you fancy improving the quality of SO, assuming there's no tangible way someone could answe this, perhaps answer the question yourself with a biopsy of what went wrong, or just close the question. Thanks!